# What is the actual size of the Binding Band in SMO?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

In Super Mario Odyssey, one of the items Bowser steals is the Binding Band, a hugely oversized ring. He steals it from the Sand Kingdom, so pretty early on. The main question is based on endgame and postgame content, hence the spoiler:

> At the end of the game, Bowser struggles to get it onto Peach, and it seems to be at least her full height. Yet shortly after, when you actually fight Bowser, it’s very snugly around Peach’s waist. Finally, when the ring is returned to its spot in the Sand Kingdom, it seems to be almost twice Mario’s height.

So in all three of those instances, the Binding Band varies in size. Is there any in-game explanation that I missed that explains this? Or is it an oversight in the design process?

Comment: Possibly related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134246/can-the-one-ring-change-in-size :P

Comment: @JoshB. Someone get MatPat on the line.

Comment: It's magic, they ain't gotta explain.

Answer (score 5):

Size in the Mushroom Universe is very loose in general. Things grow and shrink by touching mushrooms, body parts inflate when used to strike opponents, Bowser just makes himself as big as he wants. Yes the ring's size is internally inconsistent with no given in-universe reason, but so is almost everything else in the series.

Comment: Like what? Except in the Galaxy games where Bowser’s under the influence of Grand Stars, Bowser’s size has been roughly the same throughout.

Comment: Bowser varies from "a bit taller than Mario" (sports games) to "twice Mario" (Paper Mario) to "freakin huge" (Sunshine); even in Odyssey he shrinks down after you beat him for no obvious reason. Wario varied in size in the first games he appeared. Chain Chomps started as equal to Mario but now vary from twice to three times his size. Even Coins as they appear in the game world can be as tall as Mario or only half his size. Admittedly, most of this is between different games rather than in the same game, but it shows the series isn't too concerned with size consistency in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is probably about the size of Bowsers wrist from the cut scene before the last boss fight where Peach is in the ring.

Answer (score -1):

The binding band if you consider diameter, in several cutscenes, peach can go in the ring without any trouble and before you finish sand, I would estimate around 180 centimetres in diameter